# count element in array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have about 5.000 record, each record contain an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 96
    [1] => 40
    [2] => 86
    [3] => 17
    [4] => 18
    [5] => 23
)
Array
(
    [0] => 01
    [1] => 21
    [2] => 96
    [3] => 33
    [4] => 44
    [5] => 02
)
```

I want to get how many time element appear consecutively and into array like this

```
array (
    [96]=>2, // number 96 appear 2 time consecutively 
    [40]=>1,
    [86]=>1,
    [17]=>1,
    [18]=>1,
    ....
)
```

Any idea for this problem ???

Comment: Yes sir. I want to go througt 5000 array, each array have 27 element, count how many time element appear consecutively.

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you simplified it and if your sample output was relevant to your sample input. How about just 3 arrays with 5 elements each - show us that and what the expected output would be. Then we can expand to 5000 arrays with 27 elements each...

Comment: What if the number appears in multiple consecutive series? What code have you tried so far? http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the *max* number of times any given element appears consecutively, assuming your 5,000 arrays are in an array called `$arr`:

```
$count = array();
foreach ($arr as $k => $ar) {
    foreach (array_unique($ar) as $a) { 
         $tmp = 1;
         if (isset($count[$a])) {
             $tmp = $count[$a];
         }
         $count[$a] = 1;
         if ($k > 0) {
            $i = 1;
            while ($i <= $k && in_array($a, $arr[$k - $i])) {
                $count[$a]++;
                $i++;
            }
        }
        if ($count[$a] < $tmp) $count[$a] = $tmp;
    }
}
```

[**See demo**](http://3v4l.org/34NrH)

Comment: If I change 96 in  array(01, 12, 96, 33, 44, 02) the result of 96 will be 1, not 2, because in second array it not appear. I exactly want to get that.

Comment: It mean I change the 96 number to other number, may be 02.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I see a error. If you try array like that: $arr = array(
        array(96, 40, 86, 17, 18, 23, 96),
        array(01, 12, 03, 33, 44, 02, 13),
        array(96, 33, 05, 40, 22, 29, 33),                          array(96, 40, 86, 17, 18, 23, 96),
        array(01, 12, 03, 33, 44, 02, 13),
        array(96, 33, 05, 40, 22, 29, 33)
    );